# How do I make it so catch stops looping and goes back to the beginning of the loop

Tags: c#, while-loop

When running this code once it catches an exception it will keep repeating "The file was not found". How do I make it so it goes back to the beginning of the loop instead?

```
    private static List<Party> FindData(string exactpath)
    {
        bool validInput = false;
        while(validInput==false)
        {
            try
            {
                // Store values in a list of string
                List<string> file = File.ReadAllLines(exactpath).ToList();
                List<Party> parties = new List<Party>();
                foreach (string line in file.Skip(3))
                {
                    string[] items = line.Split(',');
                    Party p = new Party(items[0], Convert.ToInt32(items[1]), items.Skip(2).ToArray());
                    parties.Add(p);
                }
                return parties;
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"The file was not found");
                
            }            
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Example when not finding the file:
[image: Console Screenshot]

Comment: It should already be doing that; since `validInput` is never set to `true`, your `while` loop should never exit.

Comment: And as I see in your screenshot, that's *exactly* what it is doing.

Comment: It *is* going back to the beginning of the loop.  You aren't fixing the exception, so it just re-throws, forever and ever.

Comment: Try putting `return null;` in your `catch` block.

Comment: Do you mean the beginning of the _inner_ loop?

Comment: You need to do something to fix the exception in the `catch` block, this will then go back to the top of the loop and `try` it again, no pun intended

Answer (score 1):

`Break;` should do the trick. Is it what you are looking for?

```
private static List<Party> FindData(string exactpath)
    {
        bool validInput = false;
        while(validInput==false)
        {
            try
            {
                // Store values in a list of string
                List<string> file = File.ReadAllLines(exactpath).ToList();
                List<Party> parties = new List<Party>();
                foreach (string line in file.Skip(3))
                {
                    string[] items = line.Split(',');
                    Party p = new Party(items[0], Convert.ToInt32(items[1]), items.Skip(2).ToArray());
                    parties.Add(p);
                }
                return parties;
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"The file was not found");
                break;
            }            
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Although, what's the whole point of `validInput` then?